# How can I use the Google OAuth2 ID token with node.js / passport.js to verify if the user is valid and authenticated?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, google-oauth

On my front end, I'm using `vue.js` (not that that matters) and with the Google OAuth flow, I get back an `id_token` from:

```
let googleAuthIdToken = await this.auth2.currentUser
            .get()
            .getAuthResponse().id_token;
```

I want to then pass that token to my node.js server (Express / Passport) to verify that the user is allowed to login.

I want to use passport and send back a JWT to the front end in my response.

Can someone please guide me as to how to accomplish this?

Comment: In that specific case, passport is redundant with your frontend OAuth flow.
I would register the token on sign-in by sending it to express and store it into a user table on your favorite DB. Then I would issue the jwt and keep that as well in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to make use of a node module called `googleapis`, After installation, import the module.

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';
```

Then you need to create an OAuthClient by specifying the `CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL`.

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URL,
);
```

Then you can get the token from google by using the `oauth2Client`.

```
const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
```

Inorder to obtain the neccessary user information to store in your own database, You need to call this method.

```
const plus = google.plus({ version: 'v1', oauth2Client });
const me = await plus.people.get({ userId: 'me' });
```

`me` will contain the user information that you are looking for, once you obtain the user information you can then store it using passport js.

Comment: Why do I need a REDIRECT_URL? I already have the user doing that oauth flow on the client side.

Comment: @Shamoon You can specify the optional ```REDIRECT_URL``` while you are configuring google plus API in the google developer console.

Comment: I'm specifying the REDIRECT_URL when I am configuring my oauth client in the developer console. So why do I need it here? And secondly, I already have the code.